# The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 301d0000000bufQ

Tags: apex, process-builder

I am new to process builder. There are many process in our org with different version of the process. I was wondering when i get this error what that version id means that salesforce is showing in the error.

When i am searching like `https://test.salesforce.com/301d0000000bufQ`.
Its showing this record id doesnt exist.

Wouldnot it suppose to be in salesforce.

How can i debug as there are many processes exist in org with different 
versions.

Complete error would go to opportunity owner or to the developer who has created the process builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process builder doesn't have tools for debugging. All you have - is an beautiful error email report.

There is high probability that you have new validation on your object and flow can't provide changes.

Goto developer console -> query editor -> check `use tooling api` -> execute query: `select fullname from flow where id = '301...'` -> find flow by its name -> provide validation changes.

But in future, your admin can add new validation to object in production. Then you again will have similar issue. Process builder is a fancy tool, but I prefer user trigger instead.

Answer (score 1):

The version id mentioned in error message is the Id of the process builder and we will not be able to find the process builder by adding this Id next to the instance URL.

There is one way to find out the process builder that has thrown error message, based on version Id. You can login to Workbench using your Salesforce credentials, and click on "MetadatTypes & Componenets" under Info, select flow in pick-list displayed. Then click on "Expand All" link provided and you can find the relative process builder name by searching with version id.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must have got the versionID of the process builder, you can check that On workbench via Utilities > REST Explorer, where you can mention the ID as per below
[image: REST CALL]

Moreover if you find field "ProcessType" as Workflow then that means it is process builder, otherwise it is VisualFlow.
Rather than checking the components, I find this as an easy way out.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Flow Version Id, append it to the flow designer url and it'll directly open the offending Flow or Process Builder. For example, if the Flow Version Id is 3010L0000000pjV in the error, open "https://...salesforce base url.../designer/designer.apexp#Id=3010L0000000pjV"

Alternatively, you can install the [Boostr for Salesforce Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boostr-for-salesforce/kegohbhdgaoaoanbpconbeleanhdodlo) and it'll build that link and add it to the generic flow error page or when that error is shown in a unit test detail in Salesforce classic. See my comment in this [Stack Exchange post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140402/a-flow-trigger-failed-to-execute-the-flow-with-version-id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/) for more information.