# A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Tags: flow

"Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow 
The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. 
A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.

Solution as per Success community :
The above is expected behavior, and is working as designed. If you should encounter this error, there are a few steps you can take to fix it: 
Review all code/processes/etc. which trigger the flow, and update the API version to be compatible with all fields in the flow. Each field should have a minimum API version dictated in the SOAP Api Developer's Guide article for the relevant object.

How do I go ahead with the Solution /Where to check the version?

Comment: What is triggering the error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had this error and it's hard to find the actual name of the flow so that you can deactivate/fix it.

I found the easiest way (outside of performing your own metadata query) is to use Workbench https://workbench.developerforce.com.

[image: Select Metadata Types and Components]

Then, choose FlowDefinitions and Expand All. This will display all FlowDefinitions on the page, and will include the id that you are looking for.

[image: FlowDefinitions Expanded View]

Now you can do a simple Browser text search for your ID `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, which will also reveal the flow name, allowing you to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to identify the "Offending" flow or process builder when the generic flow error is shown in Salesforce Classic, use the Boostr for Salesforce Chrome Extension. When this error is shown, the extension adds a "View Offending Process Builder or Flow" link that opens the flow designer with the offending process builder or flow.

[image]

Clicking "View Offending Process Builder or Flow" opens the Flow Designer with the Flow Version Id to show the process builder or flow that caused the error.

[image]

Note: Even though the flow designer is opened, a process builder may actually be causing the issue. A process builder opens successfully in the flow designer because under the hood it really is a flow.

I originally added this enhancement because when you don't receive the Flow error email, it's challenging to determine the offending flow or process builder, especially if there are many of them.

Comment: Can you include the relevant content here? In the end the secret is just to build a link, right? Answers which only contain a link to your blog or a tool you developed can easily be misconstrued (and the link(s) could also go dead).

Comment: @AdrianLarson, Fair point. I've updated my original post to contain the essentials of my [original blog post](http://metillium.com/2017/07/boostr-view-flow-or-process-builder-causing-error/)

Comment: [Boostr for Salesforce Chrome Extension Installation Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boostr-for-salesforce/kegohbhdgaoaoanbpconbeleanhdodlo). Being a new contributor, I'm only allowed to have 2 links in my posts for now so unfortunately had to have another post for the extension link